# Touchpad not working

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, elementary-os, touchpad, input-method

I just installed Elementary OS and almost everything is working great.
The only problem is that the touchpad isn't working. I can not move the cursor with the touchpad. But if I use a mouse it is working fine.

Results when I run `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Please note the Apple Optical Mouse is a usb connected mouse. The touchpad vendor is Elan.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux

Specifically:

had the same problem. After googling a lot I found a workaround: in /etc/defaut/grub

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
I added i8042.reset to the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
and then

sudo update-grub
Finally after a restart the touchpad works fine (multitouch included).

Check that out, it may help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the problem is a bit different because when I run xinput I don't see the touchpad. I tried adding the line but it did not do something :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I updated my OS. It was fixed when I simply rebooted my machine. Please update your OS and reboot your machine and check your xinput list.

Comment: You will be surprised to see your touch pad added in the xinput list.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with an HP EliteBook 840 G3 notebook. Was running OpenSUSE Leap, and the problem was resolved by installing the "synaptics" drivers in YaST.